# Pivoting a column and sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Following is the sample table. need to pivot a column (Commission) and count of deptids

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Region varchar(10),DeptId INT,Commission varchar(10),comm_attribute1 decimal,comm_attribute2 decimal,comm_attribute3 decimal);
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('ABC',1,'HR',10,20,30);
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('ABC',3,'HR',10,20,30);
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('ABC',7,'DEV',10,20,30);
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('ABC',4,'DEV',10,20,30);
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('ABC',5,'HR',10,20,30);
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('ABC',8,'HR',10,20,30);
```

Following is the query but failed to pivot

```
WITH T AS
(
  SELECT Region, deptCOUNT, Commission, att1 + att2 + att3 AS total
    FROM (SELECT Region,
                 Commission,
                 COUNT(Region) as deptCOUNT,
                 SUM(comm_attribute1) AS att1,
                 SUM(comm_attribute2) AS att2,
                 SUM(comm_attribute3) AS att3
            FROM #Table1
           GROUP BY Region, Commission) tmp
)
SELECT * 
  FROM T 
 PIVOT (
        MAX(total) FOR Commission IN([ DEV ], [ HR ])
       ) P
```

Need following result

| Region | DeptCount | Dev | HR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 6 | 120 | 24 |
| XYZ | 2 | 100 | 200 |

[Expected Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIMbg.png)

Comment: For info on how to improve your question see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBo0.png)

Comment: @Stu - Why can't I click the link?! ... Oh ... wait...  ;-)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh its SQL DB

Comment: Which one? There are dozens of them.

Comment: @jarlh What dozens

Comment: You can find most of them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems